How to correctly reference the submodule of a Maven project
This is the maven structure of my project
dynamic-thread-pool
  |-dynamic-thread-pool-starter
    |-thread-pool-domain
    |-thread-pool-infrastructure
    |-thread-pool-types
    |-thread-pool-app
    |-thread-pool-trigger
  |-dynamic-thread-pool-test

I want to use all the submodule contents under dynamic-thread-pool-starter in dynamic-thread-pool-test. I rely on it in the pom file.
# in dynamic-thread-pool-test/pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.dcy.threadpool</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamic-thread-pool-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

But I still can't use its submodules.
How should I modify it?
I want to depend on the starter, rather than on each submodule in turn.

In short: this doesn't work that way. A module in Maven is basically a build time concept, i.e. once the modules are built, the information about modules is no longer relevant (and can even be stripped from the published pom).
So when you depend on dynamic-thread-pool-starter, you would get dependencies and starter and all its dependencies, not its modules.
But:
From your naming, I would surmise that thread-pool-app depends in turn on all the other modules, so the simple and correct solution would be to depend on thread-pool-app instead.
